# How do I use my Racial Power?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I use Racial Powers in Skyrim? My Dark Elf quickly got ambushed by wolves after the tutorial dungeon, and as the three of them surrounded me, I thought it would be awesome to light myself with the fires of my Ancestors, burning the wolves around me!

I equipped the spell from the magic menu, but it didn't seem to go into either my left or right hand -- so how exactly are we supposed to use them?

Comment: (PS: I got those stinkin' wolves anyway, and am now wearing them as an awesome helmet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To unleash your awesome racial powers, first go to your magic menu. Then, select your power. Finally, unleash it with the <kbd>Z</kbd> key . The <kbd>Z</kbd> key is also the key that shouts are mapped to, so you can only have one shout or racial selected at a time.

Console equivalents are <kbd>RB</kbd> on the Xbox 360, and <kbd>R2</kbd> on the PS3.

Comment: Note that on an Azerty keyboard, this is the `W` key. Fabian mentions the `Y` key on German keyboards.

Answer (score 4):

When playing on an xbox with the Kinect you need to depress both the LB and RB.

Answer (score 2):

The shout is mapped to the <kbd>Z</kbd> key (on some keyboards like the german one, it's the <kbd>Y</kbd> key), you don't need to equip it onto a specific hand. You do however need to activate a shout by absorbing a dragon soul, if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: the power he was referring to wasn't a shout.